# How do I append a variable to a url that is not a specific destination?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables

I need to append a variable to a dynamic link for downstream tracking.

Appending `?var=true` works for mysite.com/ links (I am detecting existing variables and appending a `&var=true` if they exist), but it breaks if there is no trailing '/'.

Preceding the '?' with a '/' corrects this, but then it breaks links in the format of mysite.com/info.php (path problems with CSS).

Is there a server setting or .htaccess change to allow liks in the form of mysite.com?var=true to resolve properly?

```
mysite.com?var=true     <- broken

mysite.com/?var=true    <- works

mysite.com/info.php?var=true  <-works

mysite.com/info.php/?var=true <-broken
```

Server is apache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /info.php?id=$1
```

That might do it, or a variation of in your .htaccess file

Comment: The system may work if links with variables in the form of 'mysite.com?var=true' works the same as 'mysite.com/?var=true'. 'info.php' was a form example, as the actual link will not be known.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append a variable to all urls of website, try this in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?var=true(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?var=true [L,QSA]
```

But this will not change the url in the browser of the user (he will not see the added variable but the server will). If you want it to be shown, you must add the redirect flag [R] to the last line :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?var=true(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?var=true [L,QSA,R]
```